# Delete the row you click on (Javascript dynamic table)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, row

I want to delete a row from a table, I am using Javascript.
I am dynamically creating table rows and in the last cell I have delete button so how to make it delete the row?

```
var newData4 = document.createElement('td');
                var delButton = document.createElement('input');
                delButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                delButton.setAttribute('name', 'deleteButton');
                delButton.setAttribute('value', 'Delete');
                newData4.appendChild(delButton);
                newRow.appendChild(newData4);
```

this is the function for creating my table rows

```
    function addItem()
{
    document.getElementById('add').onclick=function()
    {
                var myTable = document.getElementById('tbody');
                var newRow = document.createElement('tr');




            //var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            //element1.type = "checkbox";
            //newRow.appendChild(element1);

            var newData1 = document.createElement('td');
            newData1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('desc').value;

            var newData2 = document.createElement('td');
            newData2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('taskPriority').value;

            var newData3 = document.createElement('td');
            newData3.innerHTML = document.getElementById('taskDue').value;




                    myTable.appendChild(newRow);
                    newRow.appendChild(newData1);
                    newRow.appendChild(newData2);
                    newRow.appendChild(newData3);


                var newData4 = document.createElement('td');
                var delButton = document.createElement('input');
                delButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                delButton.setAttribute('name', 'deleteButton');
                delButton.setAttribute('value', 'Delete');
                newData4.appendChild(delButton);
                newRow.appendChild(newData4);
            }
    }
```

Comment: what have you tried? when you say delete, do you mean you want to remove the element from the DOM or make an ajax call to delete the row's data from some database?

Comment: @MateuszKowalik: Can you show a sample code of what you have done?

Comment: a am creating delete button for each row in my table and now i have to make each button delete its own row when clicked

Answer (score 1):

```
function SomeDeleteRowFunction(btndel) {
    if (typeof(btndel) == "object") {
        $(btndel).closest("tr").remove();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

try this code [here is fiddle](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpa9/latest/Remove%20Table%20Row%20on%20click%20del)

alternatively try

```
//delete the table row
        $(document).on('click', '#del', function(){
              $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            });

        }); //del is the id of the delete block
```

one pure javascript approach

```
function deleteRowUI(btndel) {
    var table=document.getElementById('filterTableBody');
    if (typeof(btndel) == "object") {
        p=btndel.parentNode.parentNode;
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
        var oTable = document.getElementById('filterTableBody');

        //gets rows of table
        var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
        for (var i = 1; i < rowLength; i++){

               var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
               //gets cells of current row
               var cellLength = oCells.length-1;
                   for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){
                       oCells.item(j).innerHTML = "";
                       break;
                   }
                   break;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to temporary hidden it you can do: 
this.parentNode.style.display='none'; 
in mind that the exclusion button is in a td.
But if you want to really delete it from the html and the database:
you need to make the same as above and a extra call to a function of php/plsqlwathever to delete from de db, i recommend using ajax to call it.
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

uses jQuery remove method to do it.

By the id attribute : 
    $("#id here").remove();

By the class attribute : 
    $(".class name here").remove();

I hope I've helped a little...

Comment: this is my college project and we didn't touch or jquery and anything other than javascript

Comment: @Mateusz Kowalik Visit http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/